# What is the mathematical symbol for "not proportional to"?

Tags: linear-algebra

For saying that x is proportional to y, one would write:
$$x \propto y$$

But how could I write it if x isn't proportional to y?

Comment: $x\not \propto y$????

Comment: Putting a forward slash through a symbol is generally taken to mean 'not'. Alternatively $\neg (x \propto y)$ is acceptable too.

Comment: I'm with Dietrihch Burde, I'd write "\$x \not \propto y\$" to obtain $x \not \propto y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more a question for tex stackexchange. The command "propto" can be negated by prescribing "not" to it: 
$$
x\propto y, \quad x\not\propto y.
$$
Better ideas are given [here](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=8125).

Comment: I think the OP is asking about mathematical notation rather than tex

Comment: @Shuri2060 I am not sure, but the above link discussing it is a latex-site.